# Adding user meta to post meta wp_insert_post() not working

Tags: php, post-meta, user-meta, wp-insert-post

i'm trying to add a users meta field to a posts custom field when inserting a post using `wp_insert_post()` but it isn't working. I've tried replacing the `$branch` with a simple string and it works but when i enter a variable with the `wpcf-branch-active` in it doesn't show anything.

Can anyone help me please?

```
$my_order = array (
           'post_type' => 'saved-orders',
           'post_title' => date('Y-m-d'),
           'post_content' => $ordercart,
           'post_status' => 'publish',
           'comment_status' => 'closed',   // if you prefer
           'ping_status' => 'closed',      // if you prefer
        ); 


        $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_order);
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        $branch = get_user_meta($user_id, "wpcf-branch-active", true); 

        add_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-branch-order', $branch, true);
```

Comment: what is in the variable you want to save ? If it's an object linked to ressources, that doesn't works because ressources are not saved from one PHP to another.

Comment: I want the value of $branch to be stored. If i echo $branch then i get a single value so i dont think it's an object..

Comment: Have you tried using update_post_meta? I’m assuming a var_dump after the $branch statement to make sure get_user_meta is grabbing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `add_post_meta` with the argument `$unique = TRUE` and the meta already exist, the value is not changed
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

If you want to update a meta, use `update_post_meta`

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-branch-order', $branch);
```